# Query returns ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle

I am running the following query, trying to find the existence of first inserted row's duplicate instance:-

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM rlx_service_info
    WHERE row(personalaccountid,serviceid,serviceline,
              userserviceid,servicerf) IN (SELECT personalaccountid,
                                                  serviceid,
                                                  serviceline,
                                                  userserviceid,
                                                  servicerf
                                             FROM rlx_service_info
                                            WHERE masteraccountid = 'x'
                                              AND status          = 30
                                              AND rownum          =1
                                            ORDER BY startdate );
```

Comment: Use of `row()` is not valid in Oracle.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov No wonder I was unable to find the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the duplicate rows using analytic functions (without the need for a second table scan):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT r.*,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY personalaccountid,
                          serviceid,
                          serviceline,
                          userserviceid,
                          servicerf
             ORDER BY     startdate
           ) as rn,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN masteraccountid = 'x' AND status = 30 THEN 1 END )
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY personalaccountid,
                          serviceid,
                          serviceline,
                          userserviceid,
                          servicerf
           ) as ct
  FROM   rlx_service_info r
)
WHERE ct > 0
AND   rn > 1;
```

If you just want a count of the rows then change the outer query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN masteraccountid = 'x' AND status = 30 THEN 1 END )
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY personalaccountid,
                          serviceid,
                          serviceline,
                          userserviceid,
                          servicerf
           ) as ct
  FROM   rlx_service_info r
)
WHERE  ct > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the syntax, you have to remove the `row` and the `order by` clause.
Also, if the subquery only gives one row (`rownum = 1`) you don't need an `IN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM rlx_service_info
 WHERE (personalaccountid,
        serviceid,
        serviceline,
        userserviceid,
        servicerf) = (  SELECT personalaccountid,
                                serviceid,
                                serviceline,
                                userserviceid,
                                servicerf
                           FROM rlx_service_info
                          WHERE     masteraccountid = 'x'
                                AND status = 30
                                AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

For example:

```
SQL> select 1
  2  from dual
  3  where (1, 2) in ( select 1, 2 from dual);

         1
----------
         1

SQL> select 1
  2  from dual
  3  where row(1, 2) in ( select 1, 2 from dual);
where row(1, 2) in ( select 1, 2 from dual)
               *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

However, if you need the subquery to only return one row with the minimum `startDate`, consider that an `order by` in combination with a `rownum` condition is not a way; you'll find many good answers on how to do this.

For example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (
  3          select 1 x from dual union all
  4          select 2 x from dual
  5       )
  6  where rownum = 1
  7  order by x;

         X
----------
         1

SQL> select *
  2  from (
  3          select 2 x from dual union all
  4          select 1 x from dual
  5       )
  6  where rownum = 1
  7  order by x;

         X
----------
         2
```

Comment: It says ORA-00920: invalid relational operator at the last line, cannot figure out why

Comment: @SohamBanerjee Remove `order by` clause - not allowed in that subquery. And it,  frankly speaking, makes no sense to have it there.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov But I need to check whether the first service existing had a previous record (probably inactive)